# Windows Azure Free Trial

Tags: windows, azure

I already have a profile on a Windows Azure. How can I delete my Windows Azure profile or how can I get free trial(if I already create a account)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Canceling the Subscription : http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/cancel-account/

Free Trial : http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/